# Convert Month name and date to yyyy-mm-dd Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert date column and some special character to yyyy-mm-dd format, yyyy is this year, **Fri** convert to this friday,  which is 2021-08-13

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

data = [['vvv', 'Apr 22','broken'], ['fewfew', 'Fri','dfs'], ['Acer', 'May 5','exckia'], ['Blackberry', 'Jan 18','exAsus']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Brand', 'date', 'Description'])
```

[image]

expected result

[image]

my approach doesn't work

```
df['YYMMDD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_datetime()`+`fillna()`:

```
df['date']=(pd.to_datetime('2021 '+df['date'],errors='coerce',format='%Y %b %d')
              .fillna(pd.Timestamp('2021-08-13')))
```

output of `df`:

```
    Brand       date        Description
0   vvv         2021-04-22  broken
1   fewfew      2021-08-13  dfs
2   Acer        2021-05-05  exckia
3   Blackberry  2021-01-18  exAsus
```

For more information regarding format code visit [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: cool answer, can you please explain errors='coerce' , and why format='%Y %b %d', what is b?

Comment: @PyBoss when `to_datetime()` found any date that are not in format `'%Y %b %d'` or incorrect dates then instead of throwing errors it will convert those dates to `NaT` and continue further parsing

Comment: @PyBoss Since we are adding '2021 ' to the 'date' series so the format become %Y for year %b for abbreviated month name and %d for the date....updated my answer...added link of dateformats...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: would it be possible to make it automatically to get this coming friday? instead of hard coding pd.Timestamp('2021-08-13'). AND get 2021 automatically, instead of hard code 2021?

Comment: @PyBoss well this is a different seperate question!!

Comment: @PyBoss and I don't think so there is a way!!! you can create a dict to map date at particular day....btw you can try conidering asking a seperate question regarding this and closing this question by accepting answer...Thanks :)

Comment: @PyBoss  let's say if we build logic on automatically filling dates so? 1 thing I didn't understand the above date is `2021-04-22` so on that day is `Thursday` so how friday is `2021-08-13`

Comment: if there's a month name with date, then convert to current year YYYY-MM-DD, if it's Fri, then convert to this week's friday

Answer (score 0):

Make sure at least your date have same format, and you should fix the row only provide 'Fri' info. Second, You must give the year of each date, then pd.to_datetime function will work. Finally, your code may look like below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt
    import numpy as np        
    data = [['vvv', '2021 Apr 22','broken'], ['Acer', '2021 May 5','exckia'], ['Blackberry', '2021 Jan 18','exAsus']] 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Brand', 'date', 'Description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is my two cents :

First import `datetime` module :

```
import datetime
```

Second get current date (for year replacment) :

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Third filter rows which is missing years :

**Below code will help if you want to apply to other than shared sample data:*

```
df.loc[(~df['date'].str.contains('20\d{2}',regex=True)), 
                                 'YYMMDD'] = df['date'] + " " + str(now.year)
```

Then replace the Fri missing month & convert to datetime :

```
df.loc[(df['Brand'] == 'fewfew'), 'YYMMDD'] = '2021-08-13'


df['YYMMDD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYMMDD'])
```

Comment: it ends up with error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'str'